# Set time limit for process and write stderr to a text file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I am writing a judge of competitive programming in Ubuntu and C++. What I want to do is to set time limit for a running program and also print runtime error (if has) to a text file. For example I would like to use this kind of command to set time limit for running ./test to 3 seconds and write errors to file errors.txt:

```
timeout 3 { ./test; } 2> errors.txt;
```

However terminal says that:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

How could I write a command so that it fulfill these 2 requirements (set time limit and write errors to file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to write this:

```
{ timeout 3 ./test; } 2> errors.txt
```

or more basically:

```
timeout 3 ./test 2> errors.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one works but the second one does not, because when ./test gets segmentation fault, it will not print "Segmentation fault" to file errors.txt